# Get web application ip and port on ServletContextListener

Tags: jsf, web-applications, weblogic, servletcontextlistener

I want to get my web application ip and port on start of server? For example within my ServletContextListener class. But i could not get them using neither FaceContext nor ServletContextEvent.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestServerName()
```

Using code like above will result in Unsupported method.

Since it need for a thread which run from the start of our application, we could not wait until some request send to our server.

Our application using jsf2, primeface and run on weblogic 10.3.6

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the HttpServletRequest, like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
request.getLocalAddr();
request.getLocalPort();
```

Comment: erh didnt i mention before that we could not wait till someone send a request to our server ? since we need at the start of our server, getRequest will return in null, so this answer is not work

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed that part... There's no standard way of accessing which IP en which port is exposed by the web server from the application. In fact, the web server could be configured to expose a single web app in multiple ports. Perhaps WebLogic has a propietary API to do this, but I'm not aware of any. Perhaps if you clarify _why_ you need to find de IP and the port, we can come up with a clever solution...

Comment: We have multiple server which each have a thread to create file. These thread start on the start of our server which normally start mid night which no user login at that time. Well because of some stupid reason, we didn't have a share resource like FTP or a san storage so each server create their file on their own server. so when our user login into server A, but file is on server B, we need server B link so user can get the file. Something like that.